# Have KIF tap a view where only part of text is known

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, ios-ui-automation, kif

I am wanting to log out of our app but the static text to click say something like

"Logout  (user@email.com)"

If I don't know the email address is there still a way to tap this view with KIF?

Maybe with wildcards or something?

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Logout   (*)"];
```

Comment: The lack of a way to use `NSPredicate` or a block to match the accessibility label is certainly a limitation of [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF). Although since **you** drive the UI of the app you should have access to the email address value. How did you login in the first place? Maybe if you share more details of what the test is doing, and the flow is taking, we could give you some suggestion on an alternative way to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

In Apple's UIA this is done with Predicates. So for example let's say you had a basic application, with a single view. This view contains three buttons, the labels are respectively "First Button","Second Button", "Third Button".Then you basically you can say something like

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var firstButton = app.mainWindow().buttons().firstWithPredicate("name beginswith 'First'");
```

After peeking a bit at KIF's git repo they have a class named KIFUITestActor. Looking at this class it looks like they have functions for using NSPredicates (which is the backend of how predicate works in UIA).

You could use the Predicates to help you get the full label of the view you wish to tap and then continue as normal.

It does not appear that the KIF framework has a built in tapViewWithPredicate function, so some work around may be necessary.